# ParentChild to get correct ID in T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables toplevel and parentchild. parentchild table is a tree which is related to each other. Tree looks like this.

```
TREE
1
 -11
2
 -12
 --13
3
-14
--15
---16

drop table #TopLevel
create table #TopLevel
(
TopLevelID INT,
createdate DateTime
)
insert into #TopLevel 
(TopLevelID,createdate
)
select 1,'2013-03-01 00:00:00' union all 
select 2,'2013-03-07 00:00:00' union all 
select 3,'2013-03-06 00:00:00' union all 
select 4,'2013-03-03 00:00:00' union all 
select 5,'2013-03-08 00:00:00' union all 
select 6,'2013-03-09 00:00:00' union all 
select 7,'2013-03-10 00:00:00' 
drop table #parentchild
create table #parentchild
(
parentchildID INT,Parent INT,Child INT
)
insert into #parentchild
(
parentchildID,Parent, Child
)
select 1,1,11 union all 
select 2,12,13 union all 
select 4,15,16 union all 
select 5,14,15 union all 
select 3,2,12 union all 
select 6,3,14 


;with abc as 
(
select * From #parentchild
left outer join #TopLevel on #parentchild.Parent=#TopLevel.TopLevelID
)
select * from abc
```

I need to find toplevelid for each row in #parentchild table. For examble in #parentchild table parent=12 is not in #toplevel table because its child too. then if we see child =12 and parent is 2, that is in #toplevel table.

please help. Thanks.

Data should be look like this in #parentchild table. * one i added manually.

```
parentchildID  Parent Child TopLevelID  createdate
1              1      11    1            2013-03-01 00:00:00.000
2              12     13    *2          *2013-03-07 00:00:00.000
4              15     16    *3          *2013-03-06 00:00:00.000
5              14     15    *3          *2013-03-06 00:00:00.000
3              2      12    2            2013-03-07 00:00:00.000
6              3      14    3            2013-03-06 00:00:00.000
```

Where I am doing wrong?

```
;with abc as 
(
    select ParentChildID,Parent,Child,TopLevelID,CreateDate From #parentchild
    left outer join #TopLevel on #parentchild.Parent=#TopLevel.TopLevelID
)
,xyz as 
(
    select ParentChildID,Parent,Child,TopLevelID,CreateDate from abc where TopLevelID IS NULL
    union all 
    select a.ParentChildID,a.Parent,a.Child,a.TopLevelID,a.CreateDate from abc a 
    inner join abc e on e.TopLevelID=a.Parent
)
select *  from xyz
```

This CTE is for first #parentchild table but giving nothing.

```
;with abc as 
    (
        select ParentChildID,Parent,Child from #parentchild
        where parent is null
        union all 
        select a.ParentChildID,a.Parent,a.Child from #parentchild a
        inner join abc e on e.child=a.parent
    )
    select * from abc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the recursive common table expression will be your friend here.  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683011/How-to-use-recursive-CTE-calls-in-T-SQL

Try this.  It was a bit of a rush but feel free to clean it up and play around with it. There's probably a more elegant way of doing this than using the left function.

```
With CTE as (
    select parentchildID,Parent,Child,1 as lev,cast(parent as varchar(20)) as heirarchy--,parent as TopParent
    from #parentchild pc
    join #TopLevel tl on tl.TopLevelID = pc.Parent

    union all 

    select pc2.parentchildID,pc2.Parent,pc2.Child,cte.lev + 1,cast(cte.heirarchy  + '\'+ cast(pc2.Child as varchar(3)) as varchar(20))
    from #parentchild pc2
    join CTE on cte.child = pc2.Parent
    where pc2.parent not in (select TopLevelID from #TopLevel)
),
NoDate as
(
    select parentchildID,parent,Child,heirarchy,
        case left(heirarchy,charindex('\',heirarchy)) when '' then heirarchy else left(heirarchy,charindex('\',heirarchy)-1) end as TopLevelParent
    from CTE
)
select nd.parentchildID,nd.Parent,nd.Child,nd.TopLevelParent,tl.createdate,nd.heirarchy
from NoDate nd
join #TopLevel tl on tl.TopLevelID = nd.TopLevelParent
order by parentchildID;
```

Comment: This is for one table. I have two table. Any recursive examples with two tables?

Comment: Just do a recursive CTE for your parentchild table and if the parent is null, put the child in as its own topelevel since it's a root.

Comment: You need to Union them for starters, as one CTE, not two.  I'll have a look when I get a bit of time.  Just finishing off at work.

Comment: I've just added a solution above.  Let me know if it does the job for you.